# How to open read notifications?

Tags: notification-bar, nexus-5, notifications

I got a notification which was shown in my notification bar on my Google Nexus 5. As soon as I clicked on the notification an app opened and the notification has been removed from my toolbar. With the trick described [here](http://www.labnol.org/software/android-notifications-history/28350/) I am able to see that passed notification but I cannot open it (see screenshot).

Is there a way to open that notification again so that the app leads me again to the content belonging to it?

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger image)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you want a "pinned" notification, meaning a notification that stays in the notification bar after you tap it and open the app in question.

If I am correct, you might want to look into apps that let you create your own notifications, [like the app Custom Notification.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.shekeen.WidgetHolder)

This could clutter your app drawer a little bit though; I know referencing Tasker without a specific task is poor form, but you might check into [the Tasker subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/tasker), and tell them exactly what you are looking for. Someone might be able to recommend a profile that pins a notification to the status bar until you are done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Redjax's answer: In Tasker, you can create a `Task -> Action -> Alert -> Notify` that is triggered by the notification. Just check the `permanent` box, and add an action that opens up the application in question.